New to apparmor- why are all downloaded appoarmor prifiles blanc?
background: I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.03 LTS and looking for "how to make my next installation more secure". I am interested in a topic that often relies on third party- and maybe older/not well mantained programs. I've ended up downloading this and that, snaps, flatpaks, .deb, .tar.gz, .py... Plus I'm using programs that are said to run "better" if you use the newest version from the website (such as Steam). I'm basically ruining all that's safe about Linux, am I not? What would you suggest I do in the future (given I do not want to give up my hobbies, and I'd rather not use a VM). What can I download safely, and how can I "sandbox"/"restrict" stuff? (And how to tell what's what...)
This led me to AppArmor, where all instructions - the official ones being from 2020 - say "There are loads of profiles you can download from your repo".
Yes, loads of names with their policy, I only had 2 things running unconfined, it said - but upon opening the profile files, they are all blank. Not one single line. I'm feeling tricked into feeling safe, I mean, there is neither a /path, nor a single rule what this "confined" program may do or what is denied. How is this confined?
Are all those profiles fake?
Someone should mention if they are just templates to be filled. They are not in the "templates" folder.
Is AppArmor useful, and should I learn how to create profiles myself, or do you know better ways for my purposes (see above)?
Thank you for your help.
EDIT: Main Question, profiles: adding profiles the way described on multiple websites maybe adds them to /etc directly. That's where apparmore.d contains empty ones. I found multiple snaps with different non-empty profiles. Am I supposed to add (my) profiles to the snap/etc/apparmore.d from the latest core??
An answer to my basic (security when downloading such a mixture) question would be very much appreciated. Thank you!
